# Hearthstone: Good cost minions, but with downsides?

Tags: hearthstone

I'm trying to build a strong deck with minions such as Flame Imp, Arcane Golem, Leeroy etc. that have good stats for their cost, but have downsides.
Write down/send links to as many as you know, from any class.

Comment: Are you trying to build a deck for a specific class or just asking in general?

Comment: In general, I haven't decided which class I want yet.

Comment: We need a goal you are trying to achieve.  What counts as a good cost minion?  A specific amount of mana?  Or what's a downside?  How bad does that downside have to be to qualify?

Comment: This question is not actually opinion based... MAYBE too broad a question, but not opinion based.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some, I will be adding more in. Warlock has a lot of cards like this, but there are some neutral or other class ones also. It's hard to pick cards without a definition of `downsides`. [Oasis Snapjaw](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/15-oasis-snapjaw) is a low cost minion (4 mana) for 7 HP, with the downside of having only 2 Attack.

Here are some of the ones that come to mind, sans the ones that you already mentioned ([Flame Imp](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/85-flame-imp), [Arcane Golem](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/97-arcane-golem), [Leeroy Jenkins](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/674-leeroy-jenkins)):

**[Zombie Chow](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/683-zombie-chow):** 1 Mana for a 2/3.
*-Deathrattle: Restore 5 Health to the enemy hero.*

**[Ancient Watcher](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/153-ancient-watcher):** 2 Mana for a 4/5.
*-Can't Attack.*

**[Succubus](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Succubus):** 2 Mana for a 4/3.
*- Battlecry: Discard a random card.*

**[Milhouse Manastorm](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/339-millhouse-manastorm):** 2 Mana for a 4/4.
*-Battlecry: Enemy spells cost (0) next turn.*

**[Doomsayer](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/467-doomsayer):** 2 Mana for a 0/7.
*-At the start of your turn, destroy ALL minions.*

**[Ogre Brute](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/12281-ogre-brute):** 3 Mana for a 4/4.
*-50% chance to attack the wrong enemy.*

**[Felguard](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Felguard):** 3 Mana for a 3/5 with Taunt.
*- Taunt. Battlecry: Destroy one of your Mana Crystals.*

**[Injured Blademaster](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/209-injured-blademaster):** 3 Mana for a 4/7.
*-Battlecry: Deal 4 damage to HIMSELF.*

**[Dancing Swords](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/7736-dancing-swords):** 3 Mana for a 4/4.
*-Deathrattle: Your opponent draws a card.*

**[Deathlord](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Deathlord):** 3 Mana for a 2/8 with Taunt.
*- Taunt. Deathrattle: Your opponent puts a minion from their deck into the battlefield.*

**[King Mukla](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/373-king-mukla):** 3 Mana for a 5/5.
*-Battlecry: Give your opponent 2 Bananas.*

**[Pit Lord](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Pit_Lord):** 4 Mana for a 5/6 with Taunt.
*- Battlecry: Deal 5 damage to your hero.*

**[Venture Co. Mercenary](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/509-venture-co-mercenary):** 5 Mana for a 7/6.
*-Your minions cost (3) more.*

**[Fel Reaver](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/12264-fel-reaver):** 5 Mana for an 8/8.
*-Whenever your opponent plays a card, discard the top 3 cards of your deck.*

**[The Beast](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/179-the-beast):** 6 Mana for a 9/7.
*-Deathrattle: Summon a 3/3 Finkle Einhorn for your opponent.*

**[Deathwing](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/474-deathwing):** 10 Mana for a 12/12.
*-Battlecry: Destroy all other minions and discard your hand.*

---

**[Clockwork Giant](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/12201-clockwork-giant):** 12 Mana for an 8/8.
*- Costs (1) less for each card in your opponent's hand.*

**[Mountain Giant](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/264-mountain-giant):** 12 Mana for an 8/8.
*- Costs (1) less for each other card in your hand.*

**[Sea Giant](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/614-sea-giant):** 12 Mana for an 8/8.
*-Costs (1) less for each other minion on the battlefield.*

**[Molten Giant](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/94-molten-giant):** 20 Mana for an 8/8.
*- Costs (1) less for each damage your hero has taken.*

Comment: You could add Fel reaver as well

Comment: Wow, that is a ridiculous card. Adding it.

Comment: I wouldn't really call Mogu'shan Warden a "downside" card. It doesn't *do* anything to your side of the board, it just has stats only useful to certain situations. On the flip side, you should definitely include Millhouse Manastorm, The Beast, and Deathwing.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, submitted those changes.

Comment: Ah right, doomguard

Comment: I would definitely include Doomguard; 5/7 for 5 is above the curve already, not including the Charge.